# JavaFX 2.1 CSS style warnings in NetBeans 7.1

Tags: java, css, netbeans, javafx, fxml

I've got this warnings that cannot figure them out or at least a way to hide them from my project because it just doesn't hit well on my application.

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper lookup Could not resolve '-fx-shadow-highlight-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.text-field' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/JavaFX%202.1%20Runtime/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper lookup Could not resolve '-fx-shadow-highlight-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.text-field' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/JavaFX%202.1%20Runtime/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper lookup Could not resolve '-fx-focus-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.text-field:focused' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/JavaFX%202.1%20Runtime/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper lookup Could not resolve '-fx-focus-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.text-field:focused' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/JavaFX%202.1%20Runtime/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css
```

They just link to an javafx core file and don't know how to fix these. Thanks

Comment: Provide sample code. Are you overriding default css properties? Are you creating child stages?

Comment: @UlukBiy I've proveded my css code in the answer

Comment: It is difficult to determine which css property is used in which control/situation without seeing their usage. Provide a simple small preferably runnable app, which uses the suspicious problematic css properties you have defined, **by editing your question**.

Comment: Or just try to reinstall JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {  
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/header-background.png");
}
#header .button {
  -fx-cursor: hand;  
  -fx-background-color: #cacaca;    
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , #000000 , 10, 0.5 , 0 , 0 );
}

#button1 { -fx-background-image: url("../images/dashboard-icon.png"); }
#button2 { -fx-background-image: url("../images/user-icon.png"); }
#button3 { -fx-background-image: url("../images/product-icon.png"); }
#button4 { -fx-background-image: url("../images/category-icon.png"); }
#button5 { -fx-background-image: url("../images/settings-icon.png"); }

#header .button:hover {
  -fx-background-color: #f0f0f0;  
}
#header .button:focused {
  -fx-background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#account {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/blue-background.jpg");
  -fx-border: 1px;
  -fx-border-color: #13273f;
}
#dashboard {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/dashboard-background.png");
}
.controlPanel {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/header-background.png");
}
.controlPanel .text-field, .controlPanel .text-area {
  -fx-background: none;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
  -fx-border: 1px;
  -fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  -fx-font-size: 16px;
  -fx-padding: 0 10px;
}

.controlPanel .label {
  -fx-font-size: 16px;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.validatedFields.error {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/error-icon.png");
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -fx-background-position: 265 center;  
}
.validatedFields.clean {
  -fx-background-position: -50 -50;
}
.category_label.selected {
  -fx-border: 1px;
  -fx-border-color: black;
}
.category_label.clear {
  -fx-border: 0px;
}

.level_vbox {  
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/blue-background.jpg");

}

#productPane {
  -fx-background: none;
}
#hBox1 {
  -fx-background: none;
}
```

and the other css file

```
#AnchorPane {
  -fx-background: none;
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
}

#username_icon {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/username-icon.png");
}

#password_icon {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/password-icon.png");
}

.text-field {
  -fx-background: none;
  -fx-padding: 0 40 0 40;
  -fx-text-fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -fx-border: 1px;
  -fx-border-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  -fx-line-height:20px;
  -fx-hpos: RIGHT;
}

#login_button {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/login-button.png");
  -fx-border: none;
}

#login_button:hover {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/login-hover.png");
}

#username_error_icon {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/error-icon.png");
}
#password_error_icon {
  -fx-background-image: url("../images/error-icon.png");
}
```